# Autoupdate multiple projects layers style with with same style

Tags: qgis, style

I work with multiple qgis projects, and they have the same default base layers ( cities, rivers, land use, etc.) and sometimes, one aspect of the style in changed, there is a way that this changes apply to all projects?
Something like a base style file that link to all projects?